# Where to start with OS-X 10.12 USB device drivers

Tags: macos, usb, driver

I am trying to locate documentation on USB driver development for macOS 10.12

Everything I can find online seems to be dated 2013 / OS-X 10.9 or earlier 
(e.g. https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/)

Is this because the USB drivers in OS-X haven't significantly changed since 10.9?

The documentation I can find is pointing me at USB Prober and IOUSBFamily both of which don't appear to be supported in 10.12.

Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apple's USB stack was at one time Open Source, but it was closed when they re-architected it.

The API is now dramatically different but IMHO it's better than the old API.

I found your question while searching for USB Prober myself.  It's still available at https://developer.apple.com/downloads but it's packaged inside a collection of tools whose name I just now do not recall.

I'll edit this post once I locate it.